# Calling a Class Public Sub into a Form

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

I created an Application all in Forms. I want to break the logic out into Classes. This should be rather simple. Below is my Method/Public Sub. I want to call it into a button in my form. I am not sure how to do this.expecting help from you.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Using conn = New OracleConnection(ODB)
        conn.Open()
        Me.ODB.Update(dt)
        Me.myDataSet.AcceptChanges()
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
Private Sub Update_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Update.Click, Update.Click
     Test()
End Sub
```

Comment: what is `Update5()` where it is defined?

Comment: Opps - should have said test()

Comment: ok fine.. then whats the difficulty? what are the requirements?

Comment: All I want to do is have Public Sub Test in a class and I want to call it from a button on my form... How do you do that?

Comment: You need an **instance** of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not so clear to me, but maybe that was your intent(?):

```
Public Class myOtherClass
Implements IDisposable ' optional
Public Sub Test()
    Using conn = New OracleConnection(ODB)
        conn.Open()
        Me.ODB.Update(dt)
        Me.myDataSet.AcceptChanges()
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myClassInstance As New myOtherClass ' create an instace of other class
    myClassInstance.Test() 'call the requested sub
    myClassInstance.Dispose() ' optioanl - if you implmented IDisposable in 'myOtherClass' you can dispose it when you finished using it 
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your :

```
Public Sub Test()
    Using conn = New OracleConnection(ODB)
        conn.Open()
        Me.ODB.Update(dt)
        Me.myDataSet.AcceptChanges()
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

in a module else than a class could make the job.